# Installing Spree ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I wanted to create an online shop using rails and the spree gem (http://spreecommerce.com/).

Leaving rails development rest for a while on my mac (os x lion), I installed everything from the scratch using this guide: http://tecparatodos.com/2011/07/24/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-mac-os-x-lion/ and mysql with brew.

I also followed Spree's "Getting Started Document" http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html

The issue that occured is that using mysql, after configuring the database and e.g. doing a

```
rake db:create
```

I always get the ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished error. First I thought it has to do with my mysql installation but after hours of checking and reinstalling I figured out that it actually was because of the spree gem. Whenever I add "gem 'spree'" to my Gemfile, this error occures. When I remove it and do a "bundle install", everything works fine. I have some rails experience on a view projects but spree is new to me. Any idea what could be the issue?

My database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: asiashop_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: asiashop_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: asiashop_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

And the stracktrace when I do "rails c":

```
/Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection': ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:224:in `columns'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:244:in `column_names'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rd_searchlogic-3.0.1/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:61:in `ordering_condition_details'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rd_searchlogic-3.0.1/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:52:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_core-0.40.0/lib/spree_core/find_by_param.rb:105:in `<class:Base>'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_core-0.40.0/lib/spree_core/find_by_param.rb:104:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_core-0.40.0/lib/spree_core.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree-0.40.0/lib/spree.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree-0.40.0/lib/spree.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from /Users/mark/Documents/Workspace/Asia Testshop/asiashop/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

As I wrote, it can not be a general mysql conenction problem because everything works fine as long as I do not use the spree gem.

Comment: Are you able to provide a bigger stacktrace for this issue? How did you configure your `config/database.yml`? You must've done something different as a Rails application comes with sqlite3 by default.

Comment: I am using mysql which works without a problem as long as I do not use the spree gem. I added the stracktrace and my database.yml above. Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add Spree as a gem to your `Gemfile` like this:

```
gem 'spree', '0.70.3'
```

This will install the latest stable version of Spree. The problem seems to be that Bundler is picking a very old version (0.40.0) of Spree to run, which is just plain wrong.

Comment: doesn't a latest version of gem get installed by default?

Comment: @Lavixu not if the gem dependency specifications of other gems require something other than the latest. Doing `gem 'spree'` just means "I want any version of Spree"

Answer (score 0):

Can't really pinpoint the source of the problem but after uninstalling all gems and then reinstalling them from the scratch, I got it working..